# How to set the tab as default tab in angular using angular material Tabs

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material

I have implemented a sample angular app using the Grid and Tab components from angular material.

I have implemented data bonding between the grid and tabs such that number of grid values available that many tabs gets opened up.

But addition to this I have a **ALL Summary Tab** always available irrespective of grid values.

Please access my [sample app here..](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-r4s19h?file=app%2Fgridlist.component.html)

In my app I have the All Summary Tab set as default and its active as first run my application.

But I need to have the second tab to be active as I run my app ....can any body please help me to resolve this ...?

Comment: MatTabGroup has a selectedIndex input: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup. So use [selectedIndex]="1".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can programmatically change the tab using selectedIndex.

This for example will set the tab to Ashlock, Jennifer

```
<mat-tab-group headerPosition="above" [selectedIndex]="1">
```

You can replace 1 with a variable in your component and change the index value to what ever you want it to be.